# In pandas how to classify and categorize based on values in a columns in a DatafFame

Tags: python, pandas

[Example Image (click to view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQjSI.png)

In the given image I want to add a new column "visitor type" and classify it based as the values in the column "vcount" . Like the values which is 1 in 'vcount' to be classified as single and values greater than 1 in v count to be classified as Multi. how to do that?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column of booleans :

```py
df['visitor_type'] = df['vcount'] > 1
```

You will have True for values above 1 in vcount.

Now if you want to have them labeled as Multi/Single, you can add a `map` to it:

```py
df['visitor_type'] = (df['vcount'] > 1).map({True: 'Multi', False: 'Single'})
```

Comment: Hi I wanted to add a new column in the existing df the column is to be classified as single and multi visitors based on the 'vcount' values ie 1 = single >1 =multi

Comment: Thank you very much. the question might have been naive. But i am a beginner to coding. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: You're welcome! If this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer so its taken out of the unanswered questions :)